# How to configure a roslaunch xml to run a node that specifies a path?

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run

```
rosrun ORB_SLAM2 RGBD PATH_TO_VOCABULARY PATH_TO_SETTINGS_FILE
```

within a .launch file and I don't know how to specify the path

I tried something like the following but it didn't run.

```
<node pkg= "ORB_SLAM2" type= "RGBD" args= "<path1> <path2>">
```

My example:

```
<launch>
    <include file="/home/mesa/catkin_ws/src/mavros/mavros/launch/px4.launch"/>
    <include file="/opt/ros/kinetic/share/freenect_launch/launch/freenect.launch"/> 
    <node pkg= "ORB_SLAM2" type= "RGBD" args= "/home/mesa/cavedrone/ORB_SLAM2/Vocabulary/ORBvoc.txt /home/mesa/cavedrone/ORB_SLAM2/tcp_rgbd/bin/kinect.yaml" >

</launch>
```

The error I get

```
Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: mismatched tag: line 6, column 2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292743/how-to-configure-a-roslaunch-xml-to-run-a-node-that-specifies-a-path?/) by [lyph](https://answers.ros.org/users/35575/lyph/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-05-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-05-30**:
Something like that should work. Please edit your question to include the exact launch file and the error message that you get when you try to run it.

**Comment by [lyph](https://answers.ros.org/users/35575/lyph/) on 2018-05-30**:
Okay, updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error tells you the problem

```
Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: mismatched tag: line 6, column 2
```

Take a look at your `node` tag, it's missing the `/` at the end. Change it to

```
<node pkg= "ORB_SLAM2" type= "RGBD" args= "/home/mesa/cavedrone/ORB_SLAM2/Vocabulary/ORBvoc.txt /home/mesa/cavedrone/ORB_SLAM2/tcp_rgbd/bin/kinect.yaml" />
```

Note how I added the `/` at the end of the `node` tag.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lyph](https://answers.ros.org/users/35575/lyph/) on 2018-05-30**:
Thank you! Also as a note for others I needed to add a name so I had something like `name = "foo"` into the line for the launch file to run.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-05-30**:
Np. Please click on the checkmark to mark the answer as correct.